# Cannot read property 'form' of undefined when modifying jQuery rules

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got a field that is conditionally required. As such I can't just use the required attribute in ASP MVC.

I've confirmed that there is a form and the field I'm toggling as required/not required is within that form. I can see the form tags when using View Source.

But when I try to run the following I get the error:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#myField').rules('add', 'required');
});
```

The error also occurs if I change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#myField').rules('remove', 'required');
});
```

So it isn't dependent on whether a rule is being added or removed.
The error is: `Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`

What am  I missing?

Answer (score 0):

the `.rules` requires that the parent form is validated, that is, $( "form" ).validate() is called first.

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("form").validate();
    $('#myField').rules('remove', 'required');
});
```

Comment: could you update your post by adding a snippet containing the html of your form?